# API Gateway Centralized Authentication and Authorization

Tags: netflix-zuul

I am building a microservice project in which I need certain clarification on what to do in these situations:
for centralized authentication and authorization or centralized authentication on API gateway, every request must contain jwt token and pass-through API gateway to call other microservice also it should check which user has permission to access API in other microservice. So how can I handle those situations?

Answer (score 0):

I will be using specific tool for exploitation.

users will come through either web browser or mobile app. your api gateway will be exposed to external world. most of the apiGateway nowdays contains plugins for authentication and authorization. for example you can use OIDC plugin with api gatway to authenticate the users which will return JWT token to call the internal apis. you can refer below component diagram [link for architecture diagram](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/apisix/master/docs/assets/images/plugin/oauth-1.png)